# Java 7 generics overloading compile ambiguous error

Tags: java, generics, compiler-errors, overloading

I have a transformer interface in my code to transform one object to another, or one List to another List.

```
public interface Transformer {
    <T, S> T transform(S source, Class<T> targetClazz, AfterPropertiesSetConverter<S, T> converter);
    <T, S> List<T> transform(List<S> source, Class<T> targetClazz, AfterPropertiesSetConverter<S, T> converter);    
}
```

And an implementation:

```
public class DefaultTransformerImpl implements Transformer {
@Override
public <T, S> T transform(S source, Class<T> targetClazz,
        AfterPropertiesSetConverter<S, T> converter) {
    // use BeanCopier to copy object 
    // and use coverter object to do something else
}

@Override
public <T, S> List<T> transform(List<S> sources, Class<T> targetClazz,
        AfterPropertiesSetConverter<S, T> converter) {
    // do something
}
```

}

If I call method transform like this,

```
DefaultTransformerImpl.getInstance()
                .transform(dto, PerformanceVO.class, PerformanceDTO2PerformanceVOConverter.getInstance());
```

PerformanceDTO2PerformanceVOConverter is an implementation of interface Converter.
The java 6 and java 7 complier tells me this is passed!
But if i call this method like this,

```
DefaultTransformerImpl.getInstance().transform(resList,
                            SalesPlanVO.class, null)
```

Because if I don't need do something after copy beans, I will use null instead of an implemetation of Converter.
The java 6 complier is passed, but java 7 has a compile error,

> Error: reference to transform is ambiguous, both method
>   transform(S#1,Class,AfterPropertiesSetConverter)
>   in DefaultTransformerImpl and method
>   transform(List,Class,AfterPropertiesSetConverter)
>   in DefaultTransformerImpl match [ERROR] 
>       T#1 extends Object declared in method transform(S#1,Class,AfterPropertiesSetConverter)
>       S#1 extends Object declared in method transform(S#1,Class,AfterPropertiesSetConverter)
>       T#2 extends Object declared in method transform(List,Class,AfterPropertiesSetConverter)
>       S#2 extends Object declared in method transform(List,Class,AfterPropertiesSetConverter)

I don't understand what is the difference between using null and using an object as the last parameter.

Comment: You can make it compile by explicitly casting `null` to the required type. E.g. `(AfterPropertiesSetConverter<String, Integer>) null`.

Comment: @PaulBoddington It works, but why should change null to (AfterPropertiesSetConverter<String, Integer>) null ?

Comment: Because both signatures apply otherwise, so it's ambiguous. null could also be cast to AfterPropertiesSetConverter<List<String>, Integer>, making the other overload applicable. The reason I made this a comment rather than an answer is I'm not entirely sure why the null version compiled in Java 6. It shouldn't compile in either version according to the rules for choosing an overload.

Comment: @PaulBoddington I think I made a mistake. I just use java 6 to compile this code again, it also can not be passed.